# SQLSTATE[23000] On non empty column [ANGULAR 5 & NODEJS]

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 and a NodeJS API (using express).

I'm trying to save some data from a form to my "training" table but I'm getting this error:

> code":"ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR","errno":1048,"sqlMessage":"The field
>   'denivele_positif' cannot be null
>   (null)","sqlState":"23000","index":0,"sql":"Insert into trainings
>   values(NULL,20,'00:50:00',NULL,NULL,'2018-01-01',NULL)

I don't know why I get this error because the data are correctly sending, here's what I get with Firefox network debugger in the "Params" tab

[image: what I get with Firefox network debugger in the "Params" tab]

Here's my table [image: my table]

I think the problem come from the API so here's my "router.post" function

```
router.post('/', function(req,res,next) {

Training.addTraining(req.body, function (err, count) {
    if (err) {
        res.json(err);     // Si une requete est fausse on retourne un JSON "satus: false"
    }
    else {
        res.json(
            {status: true}
        );      // Si une requete est vraie on retourne un JSON "satus: true"
    }
});
```

And my "addTraining" function:

```
addTraining:function(trainings,callback){
    console.log(trainings);
    return db.query("INSERT INTO `trainings` (`id`, `distance`, `temps`, `denivelePositif`, `deniveleNegatif`, `date`, `userEmail`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [trainings.id, trainings.distance, trainings.temps, trainings.denivelePositif, trainings.deniveleNegatif, trainings.date, trainings.userEmail],callback);
},
```

I did a console.log of my object "*trainings*" in my "*addTraining*" function** just before the "*Insert into ...*" and the "*trainings*" object contain all my value, so there's a problem with my SQL query (I think)...

[image: console.log_result]

Please tell me if you want anything.

Thanks you for your help

Regards,

Comment: You have typos: `trainings.denivelePositif, trainings.deniveleNegatif` should be `trainings.denivPositif, trainings.denivNegatif`.

Comment: Also, `trainings.userEmail` should be `trainings.emailUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar, it was some typos in my "addTraining" function, now it's:

```
addTraining:function(trainings,callback){
    console.log(trainings);
    return db.query("INSERT INTO `trainings` (`id`, `distance`, `temps`, `denivelePositif`, `deniveleNegatif`, `date`, `userEmail`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [trainings.id, trainings.distance, trainings.temps, trainings.denivPositif, trainings.denivNegatif, trainings.date, trainings.emailUser],callback);
},
```